# Echo variable from frontend in widget dashboard form

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables, widget

I create a WordPress widget and want to echo $widget_id variable inside

```
   function form($instance);
```

to be visible inside WP dashboard. Variable exists https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_dashboard_widget and is echoed in frontend using

```
 function widget( $args, $instance )
```

without issues. Is that possible? (when I try to echo variable I get notice that variable is undefined, and it is not displayed)

Comment: seems like a complicated question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function my_function( $widget, $return, $instance ){
   echo $widget->id; 
 }
 add_action( 'in_widget_form', 'my_function', 1, 3 );
```